# Mouse cursor won't change when rolling over objects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouseover, jsplitpane

I'm having an issue with a GUI I built. I'm trying to set different cursor changes when rolling over certain objects- i.e., hand cursor when hovering over buttons and text cursor when hovering over textfields. However, the appropriate code doesn't work. I've tried both the following codes:

```
classArmBtn.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

And

```
classAlcBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

I know, however, that the reason the cursors won't change is because these objects are in panels that are nested within a JSplitPane. The JSplitPane, however, is disabled because I don't want it to be allowed to resize. Is there any way to maybe override a method and allow these cursors to change? Thanks!

Comment: Normally you'd set the cursor in MouseEvent.mouseEntered. Is that where you are calling setCursor?

Comment: @ControlAltDel well there isn't a need to set it in MouseEvent.mouseEntered unless you're overriding it right? I was just calling setCursor inside my setLayout() method where I was setting the properties of each component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The JSplitPane, however, is disabled because I don't want it to be allowed to resize.

Another way to disable resizing is to disable the divider only and remove the MouseListener from the splitpane divider:

```
BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI();
BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ui.getDivider();
divider.setEnabled( false );

for (MouseListener ml: divider.getListeners(MouseListener.class))
    divider.removeMouseListener( ml );
```

Now the cursor can be set since the component isn't disabled.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks so much! By the way, do you have any idea how I can change the color of the flashing text cursor inside the text fields?